# How to use Nullable<T> if T is a type arg?

Tags: .net, generics, nullable

```
class Test<T>
{
    T? obj;
}
```

Error:

> The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as
>   parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'

I need to keep a possibly null reference to type T, but T can be either a value type or a reference type, and you can't have `Nullable<T>` if T is a reference type. Any solution?

Comment: To clarify, you need `Test` to support both classes and structs as the `T` parameter?

Comment: Please include error messages in posts -- it makes them more searchable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to support both classes and structs inside `Test<T>`, you could not use the `where T : struct` constraint and you would not be able to support the `T?` directly, although you could achieve the desired effect via the semantics of what `T?` does.

```
class Test<T>
{
    T obj;
    bool hasValue; 
}
```

So where you would use `obj`, you would first check `hasValue` to see if it is in a usable state ("non-null").

You could go a step further and encapsulate this to essentially roll your own nullable wrapper (perhaps nest it inside `Test` so as to not make it part of the publicly visible API) to support both classes and reference types. While it would be redundant, it would bring together the currently separate concepts of a null class and null struct.

Answer (score 12):

Only value types can be nullable (reference types are by their nature already nullable). So you could apply the same generic constraint as the [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) class:

```
class Test<T> where T: struct
{
    T? obj;
}
```

which of course is the same as:

```
class Test<T> where T: struct
{
    Nullable<T> obj;
}
```

and illustrates that the generic argument must satisfy the same constraints.